# How to convert List<T> to IMongoCollection?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to convert list of T to IMongoCollection, getting error 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' to type 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection`1'

Is there way to do this?

Basically I am trying to mock ImongoCollectiondata and assign list of data to ImongoCollection.

eg:
IMongoCollectioncollection
collection=(IMongoCollection )lst

Comment: Maybe it's not always possible to convert type A to type B? Why do you think that `List<T>` implements interface `IMongoCollection`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here - an `IMongoCollection` refers to a collection within the database (hence why you can call update methods on it), whereas a standard List has none of that context.

Comment: Actually I want to mock this list becasue I don't want to get from database, getting from mock data. For that I want to put those data on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only implicitly cast objects to types they inherit from.

In this case, IMongoCollection doesn't inherit from List or any of its superclasses.

What you could do is implement an extension method on List to convert to an IMongoCollection.

[Here's some more information about extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)